# getting rest service using angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, rest

I am new in angular. I am trying to get the information from a rest services that have the following JSON format

```
[{ "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 1, "participantId": 2 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 1, "participantId": 8 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 2, "participantId": 7 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 3, "participantId": 7 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 3, "participantId": 8 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 4, "participantId": 1 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 5, "participantId": 9 } },
 { "participantMemberPK": { "memberId": 6, "participantId": 10 } }]
```

My factory is returning:

```
return $resource(restUrl, {}, {
    get: {
        method : 'GET',
        params : {},
        isArray: true }
    }
};
```

When running the application I get an error:

```
Error: a.push is not a function
fa@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:11:302
Resource@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-resource.js:401:9
resourceFactory/</Resource[name]/promise</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-resource.js:482:19
n@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:7:308
resourceFactory/</Resource[name]/promise<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-resource.js:481:17    
f/<@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:120:98
hf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:134:387
hf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:131:419
hf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:135:159
l@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:87:139
N@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:91:187
Rf/</x.onload@http://127.0.0.1:8020/angularBIOS/scripts/angular.min.js:92:220
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you put a minimal example on Codepen, or JSBin, or similar?

Comment: What is "a" before the .push?

Comment: I added my code in codepen as @kiswa suggested. It seems that it is working now [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOYLyp?editors=101). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See zancudo's comment below for the solution (it was just some missing lines).

Comment: hi @kiswa.  in my code, I didnt include these lines correctly following the corresponding json format {{m.participantMemberPK.memberId}}
     {{m.participantMemberPK.participantId}}

Comment: @zancudo Ah, okay. Maybe put that as an answer and mark it so future visitors know what the problem was? Or I can edit mine if you'd prefer.